# How to read multiple check boxes in PERL-CGI

Tags: forms, perl, cgi

I have a form that have multiple checkboxes(All that apply) and I'm trying to read all the values selected....the user click submit it reloads the page and check for "post" and if is a new entry....but it only reads the first value selected and I don'w know what am I doing wrong ;/

```
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="sections" value="Cars">Cars</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="sections" value="Trucks">Trucks</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="sections" value="Airplanes">Airplanes</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="sections" value="Cell Phones">Cell Phones</label> 

sub post
{ 
  if($id1 == 'active')
  my @sections = $POST->{sections}->[0];

}
```

Comment: What is `$POST`? That's not part of CGI.pm. Your code has syntax errors. Please [edit] your question and show your **real code**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few obvious problems in your code.

1. You're using `==` when you're trying to do a string comparison. Use `eq` instead.
2. Your `if` syntax is wrong. In Perl, you need to use braces - `if (...) { ... }`.
3. You are explicitly asking for the first element from the array of checkboxes. You need `@{ $POST->{sections} }` to get all of the values.

So, all in all, your subroutine should probably look like this:

```
sub post
{ 
  if ($id1 eq 'active') {
    my @sections = @{ $POST->{sections} };
    # Do something else with @sections
  }
}
```

Also, I'd ask you to seriously reconsider using CGI in 2019. Please read [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) and think about using more modern technologies.

Comment: Yes, after posting the question I notice the error of why i was just getting the first value of the array...thanks a lot for your help and the tips